# Talking about some international scope

Tags: discussion, closing

So we have closed this [question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7756/where-to-buy-sushi-rice-online-or-at-a-supermarket-closed) for being to localized.  I went in and edited question because it felt like the OP was being ignored due the broken english of his question.  I don't really understand how we can accept questions that can deal with regional cuisines and not a question that could apply to a lot of the world, as I am sure that more than just the country of Malaysia has people that don't have access to an international market.

I do agree that the question is a little simplistic but we have other questions that are the same level IMO. I could see closing the question as off topic as hunting down ingredients isn't really what this site is about.  I personally would have preferred a "what kind of rice can I use as sushi rice" question, but I feel as the too localized is a terrible precedent here.

If we are going to write off 27 million people as too localized, at what point is our cut-off? Is it 50 million? 100 million?

Comment: The regional pizza variations thing is a completely different type of question, and not really a fair comparison.

Comment: i was just trying to make the point that we will address questions that affect much smaller numbers of people than this question could.

Comment: Right. I don't think it's a relevant point. We've already decided that regional dishes are on topic. (e.g. How can I make X as found in Y?) However, this specific question is an entirely different format and should not be grouped into some vague "international" category that is poorly defined. It fits a specific format of "Where can I find X in Region Y?".

Comment: @hobo true that, consider it corrected

Answer (score 1):

I intentionally didn't close that one because I was actually confused.  Until you edited the question, the author hadn't even specified what location he was referring to.  Now it makes a little more sense - although I actually did not interpret it the same way you did originally.

I think asking for online retailers is fine.  And asking about supermarket or store *chains* (i.e. across an entire country or region) is fine.  Searching for little Mom & Pop stores in a specific city is probably not.

I'm leaning toward reopening, but I want to hear from other community members/moderators first, because there might be something I'm missing.

Comment: The original question was "Where do I find sushi rice in Malaysia?".

Comment: I too thought it was OK after sarge's edit. I think the pile-on effect occurred a bit and simply having 3-4 votes was enough to push it over.

Comment: I also am pretty sure a similar question "Where can I find X in Y?" was asked, and not closed, but I cannot find it.

Comment: @hobodave I was sure there was one too but i couldn't find it either... I think it was from two months ago.

Comment: @hobodave: That would probably have been a better title; he changed it after a few hours from "Malaysia" to "Online or at a supermarket" and that was quite vague.

Comment: @hobodave: We did close one about [parsley substitutes in SE Asia](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/546/should-restriction-geography-questions-be-duplicates) but that's different - it's a proper subset of an ordinary substitution question.  And I think it was closed as Exact Duplicate, not Too Localized.

Comment: @Aaronut: Yea, there was a different one I thought.